# Entropy seems to behave in peculiar way

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, gravity, entropy

While I was learning introductory statical physics/ thermal physics, I have following doubt below

### Suppose that we have a system which is very very big, consisting of objects which are very very small (like point particles) comparable to the system but big enough.

Now, according to second law of thermodynamics the entropy of the system will increase to achieve equilibrium but at the same time gravitational pulling will try to accumulate all the objects (since, objects are quite big enough so gravitational pull will also be strong enough), hence randomness (distribution of the microstates) will decrease, isn't it a contradiction?

Any answer/comments are welcome and thanks for that.

Comment: The thermodynamic properties of such systems have been discussed many times on this site. You should try to search with keywords like "gravitation" and "entropy", for instance.

Comment: As one of the many examples of similar questions: [How does gravity increase (or, at least, not-decrease) entropy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/183614/how-does-gravity-increase-or-at-least-not-decrease-entropy)

Answer (score 0):

I happened to watch a vid on this by a Physics expert:

In short, despite of objects accumulating, collisions among them are not ideally elastic, and emit energy that spreads over the universe.

This is why Gravity also complies with the Second Law of Thermodynamics.

Here is the vid for a graphical explanation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJivcAAbE0A